# ASP.NET Core Unobtrusive Client Side Validation Form onsubmit fires even on validation failure

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

Note: This is related to .NET Core v2.0. You may find related posts but they don't address the issue I'm facing.

I'm applying [Unobtrusive Client side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#client-side-validation) validation with code as below:

```html
<form asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" onsubmit="showPleaseWait()" >
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Username" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  />
        <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Password" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="margin:auto;display:block">Log in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Good thing is it's performing validation on client side.

However, `form.onsubmit` event is fired even when the validation fails. As a result my `showPleaseWait` method is called. I believe it shouldn't be called since the form is not submitted yet due to validation failure.

Below is the model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]        
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Indifferent of the reason, you can stop submitting a form in such a way: `$('form').on('submit', e => { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); }, false)`. Of course, in your case this should occur only if the validation has failed. But I am not familiar yet with asp.net core mvc's library to tell you how you can check this in the event handler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The jQuery Unobtrusive Validation and higher-level jQuery Validation plugins do not block the submit event from being raised, which, as you've noted, means your `showPleaseWait()` function will be called whenever the user *attempts* to submit the form.

One option for making this work is to query the status of validation from within your `showPleaseWait` function, before attempting to run your own code. Here's an example:

```js
function showPleaseWait() {
    if ($("form").valid()) {
        // Your code here.
    }
}
```

This implementation takes advantage of jQuery Validation's [`valid`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) function, which:

> Checks whether the selected form is valid or whether all selected elements are valid.

I've just used a simple `$("form")` selector above, but this may need to be more specific if you have multiple forms on a single page, etc.